# Problems trying to install qalculate

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu

After running `./configure` for qalculate I get the following error messages:

```
checking for
    glib-2.0 >= 2.4
    libxml-2.0
    ... no
configure: error: Package requirements (
    glib-2.0 >= 2.4
    libxml-2.0
    ) were not met:

No package 'libxml-2.0' found
```

I am unable to install either of these packages using apt. How to install and resolve errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install qalculate 0.9.7-6ubuntu2 package from official repository with

```
sudo apt-get install qalculate
```

If you want to compile it manually you should install its build-dependencies with

```
sudo apt-get build-dep qalculate
```

and then create deb-package and install it with `checkinstall`.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to understand that the Ubuntu package name will not necessarily be the same as the "package" that the `./configure` is complaining about. There are several ways to identify the required Ubuntu package e.g.

1. search development packages using apt

   ```
   $ apt-cache search dev | grep 'libxml2'
   libxml2-dev - Development files for the GNOME XML library
   libui-gxmlcpp-dev - High-level C++ wrapper library for libxml2/libxslt (development)
   libxml++2.6-dev - C++ interface to the GNOME XML library (libxml2)
   ```
2. search for the specific `pkg-config` file using `apt-file`

   ```
   $ apt-file search libxml-2.0.pc
   libxml2-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libxml-2.0.pc

   $ apt-file search glib-2.0.pc
   libdbus-glib2.0-cil-dev: /usr/lib/pkgconfig/dbus-sharp-glib-2.0.pc
   libglib2.0-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/glib-2.0.pc
   libspice-client-glib-2.0-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/spice-client-glib-2.0.pc
   ```

From which we can see that the two required packages are `libglib2.0-dev` and `libxml2-dev`

Comment: How did you know to search for libxml-2.0.pc using apt-file and not lilbxml12? Also why did you search for libxml12 when it asked for libxml-2.0?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for you to install 'qalculate' would be to use a snap, as mentioned at https://qalculate.github.io/downloads.html

```
sudo snap install qalculate
```